# How to mount network drive as local disk?

Tags: windows, networking, network-share, mount, windows-8.1

I have some resource, which I can open by address **\\dir\bin**. I want to mount this resource on disk Z. In other words, I want to have path like **Z:\file1.txt** and get file **\\dir\bin\file1.txt**.

I tried this way:

```
C:\Users\user>mklink /Z "C:\Zlink" "\\dir\bin"
Invalid switch - "Z".
```

I tried to use **vSubst**. I have successfully mounted **\\dir\bin**, but there is no disk Z in explorer.

Comment: why not just use a regular drive mapping?

Comment: @Rex, I dont see this folder in regular drive mapping. There are many other folders, but there is no this.

Comment: From a command prompt, `net use z: \\dir\bin`. From windows explorer, `Computer/Map Network Drive`and set the drive letter to `Z` and the path to `\\dir\bin`

Comment: @Rex, I have one problem. When I set `the drive letter to Z and the path to \\dir\bin`, I submit button Finish, but nothing happens. There is no errors, but there is no any other actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have an existing Z: drive connected to something else, you will need to remove it (`net use /delete z:`). If you still have an existing vSubst configured, you may need to remove it.

For regular drive mappings:

**From a command prompt:**, 
`net use z: \\dir\bin`.

**From windows explorer:** 
Go to Computer/Map Network Drive
[image: Computer/Map Network Drive]

Enter `Z` for the drive letter and `\\dir\bin` for the path
[image: Map Settings]